# How do you make a custom Lego piece/figure?

Tags: design, 3d-printing

I have googled this countless times and there just isn't anything close to what I want.

I want to be able to print and design pieces: minifigure accessories, minifigure designs, pretty much make my own figure without going through another 3rd party. I have specific designs I want to do and it's strictly for personal use. I am just really curious about how other third parties do it.

I saw the YouTube video of how Lego makes their bricks. They have their own mixture and mold and press, impractical for single use. I am also not talking about pad printing or any kind of decal work as I have already researched different ways to go about doing it.

Comment: Because your question is more about plastic casting & mold making than specifically Lego, I think you will have better luck in Engineering.  It sounds like you're interested in silicone molds and 2-part resin casting. Google/Youtube has a lot of information on this subject as well.

Comment: I recommend getting the book Minifigure Customization. It explains all aspects of designing and casting of minifig parts and accessories. The book has two versions. The second print (white cover) is slightly updated from the first version (blue cover): https://www.amazon.com/Minifigure-Customization-Why-Live-Box/dp/1605490520/

Comment: The printing on existing pieces and the designing of new pieces are two very distinct fields with little to no overlap. Please specify which one you are interested in (and optionally ask another question for the other topic).